# Xamarin.iOS Can not resolve reference: System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to build a Xamarin.iOS(runtime v4.0.30319) project but keep getting the following error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Can not resolve reference: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll    myApp.iOS   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets 795

When I look in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Facades` I can see `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll` exists.

and when I compare `Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets` on another machine that works, there are no differences

after extensive searching I have not been able find a solution. I have also tried:

- manually adding the .dll to the iOS project
- reinstalling the .netstandard framework which is used
- deleting the solution and pulling from source control (I'm the only one affected by this issue)
- compared my set up to other working set ups

**Extra information (possibly irrelevant):** This is a cross platform solution and when built in the android environment, everything works as expected.

Comment: Because this error is provocated by many types of error or inconsistencies try all this steps, 1) delete de bin/obj folder in your project 2) delete the app of the simulator 3) change the simulator device, 4) close visual studio, 5) open again, 6)restore the nuget packages 7) clean and rebuild let me know if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was caused by a versioning mismatch.

I was running developing in on my windows machine and deploying to an iOS device via a mac on my local network.

The iOS version held on the mac differed from the version in my xamarin iOS project (the mac had been updated by another dev).

The resolution for me was to make sure both versions were the same

Answer (score 2):

I too had a similar problem but there was no `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll` on the Mac in the `/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades` folder.  However on the Windows PC, this file exists in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Facades` folder.

The solution for me was to copy the `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll` file from the Windows PC to the Mac.

Comment: That file should be created on build. You may have a versioning problem too

Comment: How do you correct a versioning problem?  Using the pair-to-Mac feature of VS, the only thing I do is keep the Mac XCode updated, and I'm running the current release of VS 2017 on the Windows PC.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue as well. My solution was to launch Visual Studio on the Mac (in my case a Mac Mini) and grab all updates for Visual Studio. One of the updates specifically mentioned the System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll issue that I had been experiencing. After the updates I was able to build the project.

**Release note of Visual Studio 15.9.4 :**
*"Error MT2002: Failed to resolve 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder' reference from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions...'" when building a Xamarin.iOS project."*
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#-visual-studio-2017-version-1594visual-studio-2017-version-1594-